# Could not load "C:\xampp\php\php.ini".

Tags: php, laravel

I've installed Phpstorm and tried to execute a laravel file, then i'm getting this error

```
Could not load "C:\xampp\php\php.ini".

Start tag expected, '<' not found


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must check that either php.ini exists in above path or not, it might happen if your installation was not completed or you has chosen another partition for installing Xampp. Also, by running the following code you can find the current path of php.ini:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

I hope it helps you.